# InternetExplorer.Application COM object's getElementById method not working

Tags: powershell, browser-automation

I am very new to powershell, and I am trying to automate a login to website, I have browsed many examples but NONE is working without errors.

For example with this very simple script:

```
$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $true
$ie.Navigate($URL)
$ie.Navigate("www.facebook.com")
$ie.document.getElementById("pass")
$ie.document.getElementById("pass").value = "Hi"
```

I am supposed to get "Hi" in the password field but I get instead this

[image: Screenshot here]

I am getting this error in ALL the examples I found, what's going on? Is this something no longer supported in Powershell?

I have windows 10.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still cle
ar and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `getElementById`. Use `IHTMLDocument3_getElementById`, e.g.:

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("email").value = "asd123"
```

You can do this for other methods as well, such as `IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName`.

I should add that I don't know *why* this works - I just used the following query to find any useful looking members on the Document object and played around with them

```
$ie.Document | Get-Member | where Name -like '*get*'
```

Comment: Powershell documentation is very poor and confusing.

Comment: I getting:  The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:5 char:1
+ $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("pass").value = "asd123"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Comment: It works fine for me using IE 11, for both "email" and "pass". Try piping `$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById("pass")` to `Get-Member` to see what members it has available (I can see one called "value")

Comment: It does have it: value                        Property   string value () {get} {set}

Comment: In that case, I don;t know why your code doesn't work but mine does - sorry :( However, as an aside, spend an hour finding out about the Powershell Pipeline (lots of good discussion on it on the net). It's a really fundamental concept in PowerShell that is really important to understand well. It's a bit different to a traditional pipeline (e.g. in Bash) as you are passing objects down the pipeline, rather than strings.